# How to prevent the following XSS attack on a url?

Tags: php, xss, filter-var

I am a complete newb in XSS. Suppose I have a url as such:

```
https://test.com?id=67_9&l=en
```

An XSS attack could be:

```
https://test.com?id=67_9'><script>alert(999);</script>&l=en
```

My inital thought was to use filter_var with FILTER_VALIDATE_URL to test the url, but from other threads, I am reading that such solution might not be 100% effective. Also, using such a solution will not strip all the unwanted string I don't want in the query parameter.

Any suggestion how I can prevent such XSS attack?

Comment: That only causes an injection if you're outputting `$_GET['id']`. Just encode that when you output and you should be fine. http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: I forgot to mention that the parameters are not only 'id'. I have several pages, all with different parameters.

Comment: Escape all user provided inputs you are outputting.

Comment: You should apply the [XSS (Cross Site Scripting) Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)